# Modify request's header using service worker with angular

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

I have an angular application with a third party tool. I would like to intercept requests generated from the third party tool in order to modify  outgoing header parameters.

I've tried to use http interceptor, but unfortunately, it only intercepts requests outgoing from my own application.

I'm wondering would I be able to intercept all outgoing requests using a service worker in angular? If so, do I need to modify the code of ngsw-worker.js file or I should integrate my code somewhere else in the app?

Thank you!